# Javascript ES6 Const can be changed when it's not allowed

Tags: javascript

I'm playing around with some ES6 and we know that const values cannot be changed/reasigned.
In that case, why is it allowed to change?

```
{
   const name = 'unchangable';
   sayName = (name) => {
     console.log(name);
   }

}

sayName('changed');
```

Comment: in sayName function name is a local variable, not your const

Comment: You're not changing your variable, `console.log` takes argument of the fat arrow function, `name` is still unchanged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not changing, you just print the value that you pass to the function NOT the const `name`.

Example:

```js
{
   const name = 'unchangable';
   sayName = (newName) => {
     name = newName; // This will make an error
   }

}

sayName('New Name')
```

Where your code is equal to the code blow

```js
{
   const name = 'unchangable';
   sayName = (someName) => { 
     // There is  no relationship between `someName` and the const `name`
     console.log(someName); 
   }

}

sayName('New Name');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand how scope and closures work in JavaScript.

Every time you create a function you are essentially creating a new level of scope. Everything **declared** inside that function is accessible by that function and every other function defined within it. For example"

```
function sayFirstName(firstName) {
   //This function can access firstName
   function sayFullName(fullName) {
       //This function can access firstName and fullName
       console.log(firstName, fullName);
   }
}
```

Every time the JavaScript engine sees an RHS operand (that is a value in the right side of `=`) and that variable is not a string, number, function, e.t.c but something that looks like a variable name, the JS engine will search for that variable in the local scope. If not found, it will traverse all scopes built on top of that

In my previous example if `fullName` was not found inside `sayFullName` the JS engine would search all variables declared inside `sayFirstName` 's scope. If not found there it would search the global scope which in the browser, it's the `window` object. If the variable is not found there either, an Error is thrown.

Now, in your code you define a `const name` in the outer scope. Then you go ahead and create a new function, `sayName`. This function has a scope of its own. Everything declared within it, including the arguments is a new thing.

So what happens when you do this:

`console.log(name);`

The JS engine sees an RHS operation, you are attempting to set the value of `console.log`'s first argument to `name`. So it searches for `name`. The first place it's going to look is the local function scope, that of `sayName`. It's going to find it there because you defined it in the arguments list. So it will never have to search outside of your function, so it will never find the `const name`.

You might as well write the function like this:

```
sayName = (foo) => {
  console.log(foo);
}
```

The result remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases where const does not work as you think it should.

- A const object literal.
- A const reference to an object.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are creating a new local variable for your function.

The shorthand function you are using would be the following in full length:

```
   sayName = function(name) {
       console.log(name)
   }
```

Name gets created inside the function and not pulled from outside of it. You should run your code with the following:

```
{
   const name = 'unchangable';
   sayName = (nameInput) => {
     name = nameInput;
     console.log(name);
   }
}
sayName('changed');
```

This would try to assign the new string to your constant and log it to the console afterwards.